# How do I search for part(s) of word(s)?

Tags: support, search

If you search for "BCD" in the search bar, it'll only return results containing "BCD" as a whole word, so "ABCDE" won't be a match. Is there (or can there) be a way to search for section(s) of word(s)?

Of course, I'm not really trying to search for "BCD." A better example would be a search for "tack exchan" in a way that returns posts containing "Stack Exchange."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can; enclose the part you are searching for in asterisks: `*part*`.

Example: [`*st*`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=*st*).

> [image]

As you can see, po**st**ing, **st**andards, que**st**ions, etc.—get caught by this search.